# How to implement exponential with fixed point numbers?

Tags: verilog, hdl

How can I implement a code in verilog that resolves a exponential equation that has numbers that must be represented as fixed point.

For example I have this equation on C++ and wish to convert to Verilog or VHDL:

```
double y = 0.1+0.75*(1.0/(1.0+exp((x[i]+40.5)/6.0)));
```

Where 'y' and 'x' must be fixed point numbers. And 'x' is a vector also.

I looked up for modules and libraries that has fixed point but none of them have exponentials.

Comment: Questions are expected to show what you have tried. When working in verilog people should be thinking about the hardware they are trying to describe. Multipliers are quite big, dividers even bigger. if possible exponential that completed in 1 clock period would synthesis bigger than most people would tolerate. You need to break the function down and split it over many clock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Verilog has a **real** data type that provides simulation-time support for floating-point numbers.  It also has an exponentiation operator, e.g., a ** b computes a to the power of b.

However, code written using the real datatype is generally not synthesizable.  Instead, in real hardware designs, support for fixed and floating point numbers is generally achieved by implementing arithmetic logic units that implement, e.g., the IEEE floating point standard.

Most of the time, such a design will require at least a couple of cycles even for basic operations like addition and multiplication.  More complex algorithms like division, sine, cosine, etc., are generally implemented using algorithms based on approximating polynomials.

If you really want to understand how to represent and manipulate fixed point and floating point numbers, you should probably get a textbook for a mathematics course such as Numerical Methods, or an EE course on Computer Arithmetic.